# GKE: 502 when stopping instance

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm having troubles with my Kubernetes ingress on GKE. I'm simulating termination of a preemptible instance by manually deleting it (through the GCP dashboard). I am running a regional GKE cluster (one VM in each avaibility zone in `us-west1`).

A few seconds after selecting *delete* on **only one** of the VMs I start receiving 502 errors through the load balancer. Stackdriver logs for the load balancer list the error as `failed_to_connect_to_backend`.

Monitoring the health of backend-service shows the backend being terminated go from `HEALTHY` to `UNHEALTHY` and then disappearing while the other two backends remain `HEALTHY`.

After a few seconds requests begin to succeed again.

I'm quite confused why the load balancer is unable to direct traffic to the healthy nodes while one goes down - or maybe this is a kubernetes issue? Could the load balancer be properly routing traffic to a healthy instance, but the kubernetes `NodePort` service on that instance proxies the request back to the unhealthy instance for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would say if you kill a node from GCP Console, you are kind of killing it from outside in. It will take time until kubelet will realize this event. So kube-proxy also won't update service endpoint and the iptables immediately.

Until that happens, ingress controller will keep sending packets to the services specified by ingress rule, and the services to the pods, that no longer exist.

This is just a speculation. I might be wrong. But from GCP documentation, if you are using preemptible VMs, your app should be fail tolerant.

[EXTRA]

So, let's consider two general scenarios. In the first one we will send `kubectl delete pod` command, while with the second one we will kill a node abruptly.

1. with `kubectl delete pod ...` you are saying api-server that you want to kill a pod. api-server will summon kubelet to kill the pod, it will re-create it on another node (if the case). kube-proxy will update the iptables so the services will forward the requests to the right pod.
2. If you kill the node, that's kubelet that first realizes that something goes wrong, so it reports this to the api-server. api-server will re-schedule the pods on a different node (always). The rest is the same.

My point is that there is a difference between api-server knowing from the beginning that no packets can be send to a pod, and being notified once kubelet realizes that the node is unhealthy.

How to solve this? you can't. And actually this should be logical. You want to have the same performance with a preemptible machines, that cost about 5 times cheaper, then a normal VM? If this would be possible, everyone would be using these VMs.

Finally, again, Google advises using preemptible, if your application is failure tolerant.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but unfortunately I don't believe this is the case. The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible) specifically say that stopping an instance simulates preemption (stopping or deleting both produce the same problem for me).

Comment: I also tried [simulating a maintenance event](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/setting-instance-scheduling-options#testingpolicies) and that also resulted in a few 502 errors while the instance was shutting down.

Comment: How is related the fact that stopping or deleting the machine simulates preemption with my explanation of why might some packets be dropped?

Comment: I'm explaining why the GCP Console is not "killing it from the outside in" but rather simulating the same preemption that the VM would experience in normal operation. Either way, do you have any ideas on how to resolve the problem and get kube-proxy to update the service endpoint faster - if that indeed is the problem?

Comment: And what is a pre-emption, if not killing the node from outside in? I'll elaborate my answer...

Comment: GCP gives preemptible instances notice 30sec before terminating them. Isn't there something that could be done within those 30sec to gracefully terminate the node?

Comment: I checked on this, and looks like k8s runs a shutdown script. All it does is `sleep 30`. I don't think `kubelet` is actually reacting on the term signal.